# Cambiar valores dentro de una consulta SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla de autos que tiene un campo de estatus. Quiero que al momento de hacer la consulta SQL si su estatus es `==1` me arrogue el texto "en espera". Si el estatus es un `2` que arrogue  "en ruta", y asi sucesivamente (son numeros del 1 al 4).

Comment: Hola, muestra  la consulta que ya tienes hecha para poder ayudarte a corregir. Tener en cuenta que si estás validando los estatus en el where de tu consulta debe ser sólo un signo = y no ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día compañero, puedes tomar tres vías para realizar lo que pretendes:

1. Realizar un `CASE`; mediante un `CASE'  le puedes decir al campo que depende del valor que traiga muestre uno u otro. Ejemplo:

   ```
   SELECT
     CASE campo_tabla
       WHEN 1 THEN 'En Espera'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'En Ruta'
       WHEN 3 THEN 'Recibido'
       WHEN 4 THEN 'Finalizado'
       ELSE 'Otro Caso'
     END
   from nombre_tabla;
   ```
2. Utilizar un `IF`; con este también decides que si viene cierto valor en tu campo muestre el que tu desees mediante la condición, de lo contrario que muestre el valor que trae el campo. Ejemplo:

   ```
   SELECT
     IF(campo_tabla = 1, 'En espera', campo_tabla) as "En espera",
     IF(campo_tabla = 2, 'En ruta', campo_tabla) as "En ruta",
     IF(campo_tabla = 3, 'Recibido', campo_tabla) as Recibido,
     IF(campo_tabla = 4, 'Finalizado', campo_tabla) as Finalizado
   from nombre_tabla;
   ```
3. Crear una tabla que guarde el estatus, es decir, una tabla llamada estatus y que tenga tres campos, uno que sea el id, otra el tipo de estatus y la tercera la descripción del estatus. Así unes la tabla estatus con tu tabla autos y mandas a llamar los campos que quieres de cada una de ellas y en lugar de poner el campo de estatus de la tabla autos, colocas el campo que tenga el tipo de estatus. Ejemplo:

   ```
   tabla 'autos' ('id','placa', 'modelo', 'estatus','duenio')
   tabla 'estatus' ('id','tipo_estatus','descripcion_estatus')
   ```

Cuando realices el `SELECT`, lo haces algo así:

```
SELECT a.placa, a.modelo, e.tipo_estatus, a.duenio
FROM autos a, estatus e
WHERE a.estatus = e.tipo_estatus;
```

Las letras que se anteponen a cada campo te sirven para establecer a que tabla pertenecen del `FROM`, espero te sirva lo indicado.

Saludos.

Comment: buen día, consulta a partir de los ejemplos que menciona.
En la opción numero 1, se puede asignar un nombre "distinto" al "campo_tabla" asignando un "as + nombre cualquiera".? Quedo muy atento.
Saludos

Comment: @CristoferGuerreroSantander, te refieres a un sinónimo?